# How disable autosave of files?

Tags: intellij-idea

"IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Community Edition"

When I work with my java project the files are auto save. Is it possible to disable auto save? It's not very comfortable.

Comment: In *File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings*, under Synchronization, do you have checked the option of "Save files automatically if application is idle for xxxx sec." ?

Comment: @harrymc I set 100 sec, but it not help. Autosave imediatly

Comment: Why not disable it totally?

Comment: @harrymc How disable it totally? Never mind if "Save files automatically " is check on or off. It's not disable autosave

Comment: My version of IntelliJ IDEA has a check-mark on this option that when unchecked it disables it.